# Is it possible to programmatically turn on the iSight camera?

Tags: macos, isight

I want to set up automatic camera capture on my mac, I am using `isightcapture` program.

However, I need to turn on the camera, do you know how I should do this ? I have very limited skills in `Objective-C` and `RubyCocoa` is not working in my environment (ruby 1.9 installed).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'turn on the camera' ?   isightcapture has always turned the camera on automatically for me.

Comment: I'm aksing that because I get: FATAL: setting data channel failed - cam busy/not connected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're aiming to do with your automatic camera captures, but [EyeSight](http://www.klieme.com/EyeSight.html) might be worth a look in to. It will allow you to take captures at predefined intervals in a range of formats, and will even produce a log of the images taken (which could be useful in your scripts?).

Comment: I would like a console application. I want to create a video of my flat over a month to see the evolution by taking periodic cam capture using crontab

Comment: I found the workaround: http://macosx.com/forums/howto-faqs/297484-howto-isightcapture-command-line-security-workaround.html